# Angular single component don't receive data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am currently working on adding CRUD functionality to a site under **Angular 10**, with a **firebase** db.

Where it gets stuck is when I get the data from a single post, with this method :

```js
// blog-posts.service

  getSinglePost(id: number) {
    return new Promise(
      ((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + id).once('value').then(
          (data: DataSnapshot) => {
            resolve(data.val());
          }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      })
    );
 }
```

This method **should** work, because I am using the same to retrieve messages through the contact form in *contacts.service*, which works perfectly.

```js
  getSingleContact(id: number) {
    return new Promise(
      ((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/contacts/' + id).once('value').then(
          (data: DataSnapshot) => {
            resolve(data.val());
          }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

I think the problem is really with my SinglePost component, because data looks fine in my BlogList component

```html
<button
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index"
        (click)="onViewPost(i)">
```

I think there is something wrong with the data, and that's what console confirms to me :

*core.js:4081 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of null*

But everything looks clean in my component, and my methods work in similar uses (contact form)

```js
export class SinglePostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: BlogModel;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private postService: BlogPostsService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.post = new BlogModel('', '', '', '');
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    this.postService.getSinglePost(+id).then(
      (post: BlogModel) => {
        this.post = post;
        console.log(post);
        console.log(post.text);
      }
    );
  }
  onBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['/posts-list']);
  }
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered a similar situation ?

Comment: Can you add your database structure in the question? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @SushanSapaliga It's the db model : 
```
export class BlogModel {

    constructor(public title: string, public date: string, public text: string, public imgUrl: string) {}
} ```

Comment: Then I guess the post you are trying to retrieve does not exist. That's why it is returning you `null`. Try manually type the docID of the data/post then retrieve the data and printing it on the console.